# What is the logic of binding buffers in webgl?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I sometimes find myself struggling between declaring the buffers (with createBuffer/bindBuffer/bufferdata) in different order and rebinding them in other parts of the code, usually in the draw loop.

If I don't rebind the vertex buffer before drawing arrays, the console complains about an attempt to access out of range vertices. My suspect is the the last bound object is passed at the pointer and then to the drawarrays but when I change the order at the beginning of the code, nothing changes. What effectively works is rebinding the buffer in the draw loop. So, I can't really understand the logic behind that. When do you need to rebind? Why do you need to rebind? What is attribute0 referring to?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't know if this will help. As some people have said, GL/WebGL has a bunch of internal **state**. All the functions you call set up the state. When it's all setup you call `drawArrays` or `drawElements` and all of that state is used to draw things

This has been explained elsewhere on SO but binding a buffer is just setting 1 of 2 global variables inside WebGL. After that you refer to the buffer by its bind point.

You can think of it like this

```
gl = function() {
   // internal WebGL state
   let lastError;
   let arrayBuffer = null;
   let vertexArray = {
     elementArrayBuffer: null,
     attributes: [
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: null },
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: null },
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: null },
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: null },
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: null },
       ...
     ],
   }
   // these values are used when a vertex attrib is disabled
   let attribValues = [
     [0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1],
     ...
   ];
   ...

   // Implementation of gl.bindBuffer. 
   // note this function is doing nothing but setting 2 internal variables.
   this.bindBuffer = function(bindPoint, buffer) {
     switch(bindPoint) {
       case gl.ARRAY_BUFFER;
         arrayBuffer = buffer;
         break;
       case gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER;
         vertexArray.elementArrayBuffer = buffer;
         break;
       default:
         lastError = gl.INVALID_ENUM;
         break;
     }
   };
...
}();
```

After that other WebGL functions reference those. For example `gl.bufferData` might do something like

```
   // implementation of gl.bufferData
   // Notice you don't pass in a buffer. You pass in a bindPoint. 
   // The function gets the buffer one of its internal variable you set by
   // previously calling gl.bindBuffer

   this.bufferData = function(bindPoint, data, usage) {

     // lookup the buffer from the bindPoint
     var buffer;
     switch (bindPoint) {
       case gl.ARRAY_BUFFER;
         buffer = arrayBuffer;
         break;
       case gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER;
         buffer = vertexArray.elemenArrayBuffer;
         break;
       default:
         lastError = gl.INVALID_ENUM;
         break;
      }

      // copy data into buffer
      buffer.copyData(data);  // just making this up
      buffer.setUsage(usage); // just making this up
   };
```

Separate from those bindpoints there's number of attributes. The attributes are also global state by default. They define how to pull data out of the buffers to supply to your vertex shader. Calling `gl.getAttribLocation(someProgram, "nameOfAttribute")` tells you which attribute the vertex shader will look at to get data out of a buffer.

So, there's 4 functions that you use to configure how an attribute will get data from a buffer. `gl.enableVertexAttribArray`, `gl.disableVertexAttribArray`, `gl.vertexAttribPointer`, and `gl.vertexAttrib??`.

They're effectively implemented something like this

```
this.enableVertexAttribArray = function(location) {
  const attribute = vertexArray.attributes[location];
  attribute.enabled = true;  // true means get data from attribute.buffer 
};

this.disableVertexAttribArray = function(location) {
  const attribute = vertexArray.attributes[location];
  attribute.enabled = false; // false means get data from attribValues[location]
};

this.vertexAttribPointer = function(location, size, type, normalized, stride, offset) {
  const attribute = vertexArray.attributes[location];
  attribute.size       = size;       // num values to pull from buffer per vertex shader iteration
  attribute.type       = type;       // type of values to pull from buffer
  attribute.normalized = normalized; // whether or not to normalize
  attribute.stride     = stride;     // number of bytes to advance for each iteration of the vertex shader. 0 = compute from type, size
  attribute.offset     = offset;     // where to start in buffer.

  // IMPORTANT!!! Associates whatever buffer is currently *bound* to 
  // "arrayBuffer" to this attribute
  attribute.buffer     = arrayBuffer;
};

this.vertexAttrib4f = function(location, x, y, z, w) {
  const attrivValue = attribValues[location];
  attribValue[0] = x;
  attribValue[1] = y;
  attribValue[2] = z;
  attribValue[3] = w;
};
```

Now, when you call `gl.drawArrays` or `gl.drawElements` the system knows how you want to pull data out of the buffers you made to supply your vertex shader. [See here for how that works](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html).

Since the attributes are **global state** that means every time you call `drawElements` or `drawArrays` how ever you have the attributes setup is how they'll be used. If you set up attributes #1 and #2 to buffers that each have 3 vertices but you ask to draw 6 vertices with `gl.drawArrays` you'll get an error. Similarly if you make an index buffer which you bind to the `gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` bindpoint and that buffer has an indice that is > 2 you'll get that `index out of range` error. If your buffers only have 3 vertices then the only valid indices are `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Normally, every time you draw something different you rebind all the attributes needed to draw that thing. Drawing a cube that has positions and normals? Bind the buffer with position data, setup the attribute being used for positions, bind the buffer with normal data, setup the attribute being used for normals, now draw. Next you draw a sphere with positions, vertex colors and texture coordinates. Bind the buffer that contains position data, setup the attribute being used for positions. Bind the buffer that contains vertex color data, setup the attribute being used for vertex colors. Bind the buffer that contains texture coordinates, setup the attribute being used for texture coordinates.

The only time you don't rebind buffers is if you're drawing the same thing more than once. For example drawing 10 cubes. You'd rebind the buffers, then set the uniforms for one cube, draw it, set the uniforms for the next cube, draw it, repeat.

I should also add that there's an extension [`OES_vertex_array_object`] which is also a feature of WebGL 2.0. A Vertex Array Object is the global state above called `vertexArray` which includes the `elementArrayBuffer` and all the attributes.

Calling `gl.createVertexArray` makes new one of those. Calling `gl.bindVertexArray` sets the global `attributes` to point to the one in the bound vertexArray.

Calling `gl.bindVertexArray` would then be

```
 this.bindVertexArray = function(vao) {
   vertexArray = vao ? vao : defaultVertexArray;
 }
```

This has the advantage of letting you set up all attributes and buffers at init time and then at draw time just 1 WebGL call will set all buffers and attributes.

Here is a [webgl state diagram](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) that might help visualize this better.

Comment: That explains so much. I'm just wondering about one more thing. I was trying to load different meshes through separate buffers and that led me to your point----"If you set them up attributes #1 and #2 to buffers that each have 3 vertices but you ask to draw 6 vertices with gl.drawArrays you'll get an error"---- Does that mean that if I have separate buffers,for each geometry(I don't know if that's a best practice) I have to call drawxxx several times?

Comment: You call drawXXX once for each thing you want to draw each time you want to draw it. How many buffers you use is up to you. Most WebGL apps use one buffer per type of data per mesh. So if a cube needs positions, normals, and texture coords it would use 3 buffers. If you then have a sphere with positions and vertex colors. That would use 2 buffers. You can combine things into the same buffer but it's more complex and generally not worth the effort.

Comment: Wow, thanks. ;)  I love how you broke it down into pseudo code using JS, which makes a lot of things really clear on a developer level. It's like a picture speaks a thousand words, where all I was getting was more questions on small details, and certain dots not really connecting - like seeing now how 'vertexAttribPointer ' works, I can now see I have to bind the array buffer FIRST . ;)

Comment: is the order important?
ok for bindbuffer in first position, but then : bufferdata, enableVertexAttribArray and vertexAttribPointer ? (in other words , when are the data flush into the shader ?)

Comment: The order is not important except if one method counts on state setup by another. For example `vertexAttribPointer` attaches whatever buffer is on ARRAY_BUFFER to that attribute. bufferData puts data in whatever buffer you previously bound. etc... No data is sent to the shader until you call `gl.draw???`

Comment: Wow, kudos for this answer, the pseudocode gives such a great explanation of an otherwise obscure API if you come from a generally web-focused background. Thank you so much!