# In WebGL how does an ARRAY_ELEMENT_BUFFER know which ARRAY_BUFFER to reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, opengl-es, buffer, webgl

I'm a little confused about usage of **ARRAY_INDEX_BUFFER** (Index Buffers) vs **ARRAY_BUFFER** (Array Buffers) and am looking for clarification / better understanding.

**Specifically, I'm confused about how (Given the presences of multiple array buffers) how does WebGL and an index buffer know which array buffer to reference?***

Using code obtained from [Mozilla's Creating 3D objects using WebGL Demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL)  as the basis, I understand array buffers are assigned and initialized as

```
cubeVerticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesBuffer);
var vertices = [
    // Front face
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

    // Back face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
     1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
     1.0, -1.0, -1.0,

    // Top face
    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
     1.0,  1.0, -1.0,

    // Bottom face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
     1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

    // Right face
     1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
     1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,

    // Left face
    -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0, -1.0
];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

And then the indices are stored in the index buffer as

```
cubeVerticesIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesIndexBuffer);  
var cubeVertexIndices = [
    0,  1,  2,      0,  2,  3,    // front
    4,  5,  6,      4,  6,  7,    // back
    8,  9,  10,     8,  10, 11,   // top
   12, 13, 14,     12, 14, 15,   // bottom
   16, 17, 18,     16, 18, 19,   // right
   20, 21, 22,     20, 22, 23    // left
 ]
 gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(cubeVertexIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

But given there is also a color array buffer defined as

```
var colors = [
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,    // Front face: white
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,    // Back face: red
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,    // Top face: green
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,    // Bottom face: blue
    1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,    // Right face: yellow
    1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0     // Left face: purple
];
var generatedColors = [];
for (j=0; j<6; j++) {
    var c = colors[j];
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
      generatedColors = generatedColors.concat(c);
    }
}

cubeVerticesColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesColorBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(generatedColors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

But then once it gets to the draw routine, the ordering is

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesColorBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexColorAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesIndexBuffer);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

I'm assuming that the **bindBuffer** method tells the WebGL "state machine" to make a generic buffer "active" and that the **gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER** makes a new index buffer active based on the current generic buffers

Somehow, I don't think my understanding of what was going on with that is totally correct. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. Specifically I'd like at some point to add additional objects, with different buffers (say a sphere or a torus, with a whole other color scheme)

But I understand the **drawElements(** just draws based on the indexes rather than the actual arrays done by **drawArrays(**

correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the logic of binding buffers in webgl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148273/what-is-the-logic-of-binding-buffers-in-webgl)

Answer (score 6):

The hidden curse of OpenGL and variants (WebGL, etc) is the state machine. When you call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer)`, the state machine sets `buffer` as the *active array buffer*. Likewise, when you call `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexbuffer)`, the state machine sets `indexbuffer` as the *active element array buffer* (or active index buffer).

When calling `glVertexAttribPointer`, the data for the given attribute index comes from the active array buffer. This is exactly how you have described it in your last code snippet. When you come to issue a draw call (such as `glDrawElements`), the active index buffer is used to index into the attributes.

> Specifically, I'm confused about how (Given the presences of multiple array buffers) how does WebGL and an index buffer know which array buffer to reference?

The most important point to realise is that a single vertex is not simply its position, but *a combination of all of its attributes*. In your case, a position and a color make up a single vertex. Now, looking at the attributes you have specified:

```
Position: | pos0   | pos1   | pos2   | pos3   | pos4   | pos5   | pos6   |
Color:    | color0 | color1 | color2 | color3 | color4 | color5 | color6 |
```

Each index in your index buffer refers to a combination of both the position and a color attribute. That is, index 0 will fetch `pos0` and `color0`; index 5 will fetch `pos5` and `color5`.

To answer your question, the index buffer refers to all array buffers that have been referenced when calling `glVertexAttribPointer`.

(Strictly speaking, an index buffer refers to all enabled *attributes*. The last parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` lets you specify an offset into the active array buffer so that multiple sets of attributes can come from the same array buffer.)

Answer (score 2):

`gl.vertexAttribPointer` tells webgl what kind of data to expect in the buffer currently bound by `gl.bindBuffer`. Then in the shaders you program how you want to use the data you provided in the buffers.

Its kinda like this. Suppose in the shader I want to use 2 buffers, A and B, where I want for each vertex 3 floats from A and 2 floats from B.

`gl.bufferData` sends an array of consecutive floats* to the GPU and the GPU doesnt know how to interpret the array of consecutive floats.

So I need to use `gl.vertexAttribPointer` to tell the GPU how the data is formated and that is basically what it does.

But, the way the webgl/opengl API is written I cannot just do `bufferA.vertexAttribPointer()` but instead I have to first set an imaginary global variable `BOUND_BUFFER` with 'gl.bindBuffer'. Then you can imagine the `vertexAttribPointer` is implemented to act on the global `BOUND_BUFFER` "instance" and does whatever it need to do.

- the float can be any valid webgl type of course.