# WebGL Error - Error: WebGL: bindBuffer: buffer already contains element data

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am trying to draw a simple circle using WebGL but am getting a few errors. I am very new to writing WebGL code and would love if anyone could explain this to me and what the problem is.

I can create a simple square using the same code but with 5 vertices and this works perfectly. But when I try to create an array using this method, it doesn't seem to like it. I am sorry if it is a trivial mistake but an explanation would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

> Error: WebGL: bindBuffer: buffer already contains element data.
>   webgl-debug.js:232:20 Error: WebGL: vertexAttribPointer: invalid
>   element size webgl-debug.js:232:20 TypeError: value is undefined

These are shown in the console. Here is the code I am using.

```
function setupBuffers() {
  //Setup the circle vertices
  circleVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleVertexBuffer);
  var r = 0.2;
  var centre = 0;
  var circleVertices = [];
  var z = 0;
  theta = 178;
  circleVertices.push(centre);
  circleVertices.push(r);
  circleVertices.push(z);
  for(var i = 0; i<theta; i++){
    var rads2deg = i * (Math.PI/180);
    var x = r * Math.cos(rads2deg);
    var y = r * Math.sin(rads2deg);

    circleVertices.push(x);
    circleVertices.push(y);
    circleVertices.push(z);
  }
  circleVertices.push(centre);
  circleVertices.push(r);
  circleVertices.push(z);
  console.log(circleVertices);

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(circleVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  circleVertices.itemSize = 3;
  circleVertices.numberOfItems = circleVertices.length/circleVertices.itemSize;
}

function draw() {
  //set up a viewport that is the same as the canvas using function viewport  (int x, int y, sizei w, sizei h) where x and y give the x and y window coordinates of the viewports width and height.
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);

  //fill the canvas with solid colour. Default is black. If other color is desiarible using function gl.clearColor (r,g,b,a)
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, circleVertexBuffer);
  gl.vertexAttrib4f(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, circleVertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, circleVertexBuffer.numberOfItems);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleVertexBuffer);
```

There are 2 types of buffers in WebGL.

- `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffers

  These buffers hold indices for `gl.drawElements`
- `ARRAY_BUFFER` buffers.

  These buffers hold attribute data (positions,normals,texcoords, etc)

When you create a buffer with `gl.createBuffer` it doesn't have a buffer type yet. The first time you bind that buffer with `gl.bindBuffer` it becomes whatever type of buffer you bound it to. If you bind it to `ARRAY_BUFFER` it's now an `ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer. If you bind it to `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` it's now an `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` buffer. Once it comes one of those types you can **not** change it's type or use it for the other type.

So, in your code you do this

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, circleVertexBuffer);
```

Which makes `circleVertexBuffer` an `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` type buffer. But then in `draw` you have this

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, circleVertexBuffer);
```

The buffer can't be both types. Change the first one in `setupBuffers` to

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, circleVertexBuffer);
```

You might find this answer helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164577/128511

Comment: I have changed that, but am still getting an error to do with types. The error is the following: WebGL: vertexAttribPointer: invalid element size

Comment: `vertexAttribPointer` has a `size` argument. The only valid values are `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. That error means you're passing something other than one of those values. `size` is the number of elements per vertex. It's because you're using `circleVertices.itemSize` in one spot but `circleVerticesBuffer.itemSize` in another

Comment: Such a trivial Error! I'm sorry for my simplicity but this has helped me so much! I will look out for errors like that in the future!