# WebGL error: vertexAttribPointer must have valid GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding

Tags: binding, webgl

I took a web demo and tried to create a javascript floorplan object.

It fails with the following error:

```
vertexAttribPointer: must have valid GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding
```

I have tried to create a MWE (or more accurately, a MNonEW) but the demo code includes two libraries.  I will leave those out but if the error is not obvious, and you need working code, I can paste those in as well.  I will provide link to the files right now.

MWE.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebGL Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../webgl.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="../sylvester.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../glUtils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="mwe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
      varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

      uniform sampler2D uSampler;

      void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
      }
    </script>

    <!-- Vertex shader program -->
    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
      attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
      attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

      uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
      uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

      varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

      void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="start()">
    <canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480">
      Your browser doesn't appear to support the <code>&lt;canvas&gt;</code> element.
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

MWE.js

```
var canvas;
var gl;

var mvMatrix;
var shaderProgram;
var vertexPositionAttribute;
var textureCoordAttribute;
var perspectiveMatrix;

var floorplan;
var mvMatrixStack = [];

function mvPushMatrix(m) {
  if (m) {
    mvMatrixStack.push(m.dup());
    mvMatrix = m.dup();
  } else {
    mvMatrixStack.push(mvMatrix.dup());
  }
}

function mvPopMatrix() {
  if (!mvMatrixStack.length) {
    throw("Can't pop from an empty matrix stack.");
  }

  mvMatrix = mvMatrixStack.pop();
  return mvMatrix;
}

function mvRotate(angle, v) {
  var inRadians = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
  var m = Matrix.Rotation(inRadians, $V([v[0], v[1], v[2]])).ensure4x4();
  multMatrix(m);
}

function start() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
  initWebGL(canvas);      // Initialize the GL context
  if (gl) {
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // Clear to black, fully opaque
    gl.clearDepth(1.0);                 // Clear everything
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);           // Enable depth testing
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);            // Near things obscure far things
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();
    setInterval(drawScene, 15);
  }
}

function initWebGL() {
  gl = null;

  try {
    gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
  }
  catch(e) {
  }

  // If we don't have a GL context, give up now

  if (!gl) {
    alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser may not support it.");
  }
}


function initBuffers() {
    var floorcoords = [
    [0, 0, 10,0, 10, 10, 0, 10],
    [-5,0, -5,5, -10,-5, -10,0]
    ];
    var wallColor = [1,0,0,0];
    floorplan = new Floorplan(floorcoords, 8, wallColor);
}

function createVertexBuffer(vertices) {
    var b = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, b);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    return b;
}

function Floorplan(coords, height, color) {
    var walls = [];
    var colors = [];
    var index = [0, 1, 2,      0, 2, 3];
    var indices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < coords[i].length; j+=4) {
        walls.push(coords[j], coords[j+1], 0);
        walls.push(coords[j+2], coords[j+3], 0);
        walls.push(coords[j+2], coords[j+3], height);
        walls.push(coords[j], coords[j+1], height);
        indices = indices.concat(index);
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        colors = colors.concat(color);
    }
    }
    this.colorBuf = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.colorBuf);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this.walls = createVertexBuffer(walls);
    this.indices = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indices);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
          new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    console.log(indices.length + "," + colors.length);
}

Floorplan.prototype.draw = function() {
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.walls);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.colors);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.colorBuf, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indices);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 24, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}

var z = -6;
function drawScene() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    perspectiveMatrix = makePerspective(45, 640.0/480.0, 0.1, 100.0);
    loadIdentity();
    mvTranslate([0.0, 0.0, z]);
    floorplan.draw();
}

function initShaders() {
  var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
  var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

  // Create the shader program

  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  // If creating the shader program failed, alert

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Unable to initialize the shader program.");
  }

  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

  vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);

  textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordAttribute);
}

//
// getShader
//
// Loads a shader program by scouring the current document,
// looking for a script with the specified ID.
//
function getShader(gl, id) {
  var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

  // Didn't find an element with the specified ID; abort.

  if (!shaderScript) {
    return null;
  }

  // Walk through the source element's children, building the
  // shader source string.

  var theSource = "";
  var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

  while(currentChild) {
    if (currentChild.nodeType == 3) {
      theSource += currentChild.textContent;
    }

    currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
  }

  // Now figure out what type of shader script we have,
  // based on its MIME type.

  var shader;

  if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
    shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
    shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  } else {
    return null;  // Unknown shader type
  }

  gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);  // Send the source to the shader object
  gl.compileShader(shader);            // Compile the shader program

  // See if it compiled successfully

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    return null;
  }

  return shader;
}

//
// Matrix utility functions
//

function loadIdentity() {
  mvMatrix = Matrix.I(4);
}

function multMatrix(m) {
  mvMatrix = mvMatrix.x(m);
}

function mvTranslate(v) {
  multMatrix(Matrix.Translation($V([v[0], v[1], v[2]])).ensure4x4());
}

function setMatrixUniforms() {
  var pUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(pUniform, false, new Float32Array(perspectiveMatrix.flatten()));

  var mvUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(mvUniform, false, new Float32Array(mvMatrix.flatten()));
}
```

The libraries used in this demo code are from:
https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/tree/gh-pages/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

gl.vertexAttribPointer() takes as its first argument the index of a vertex attribute defined in your shader.

For instance, your first call to gl.vertexAttribPointer() goes something like this:

```
// In initShaders()...
vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);
// vertexPositionAttribute now contains an index to the attribute
// "aVertexPosition" in the vertex shader
// ...
// Later, in Floorplan.draw():
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.walls);  // Data from this.walls is bound to gl.ARRAY_BUFFER
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
// The current gl.ARRAY_BUFFER is bound to "aVertexPosition"
```

But in your second call:

```
gl.bindBuffer(this.colorBuf, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

The problem here is that this.colorBuf isn't an index to a vertex attribute. If I had to guess, I'd say your code initially had a per-vertex color attribute which has been discarded in favor of texture coordinates.

So probably just get rid of that colorBuf stuff, and bind some data to aTextureCoord, and you may be in business.

Comment: The walls should be rendered in color, so I need to amend the fragment shader and get the color attribute from the shader so I can bind.  I can see my mistake, in a different example they showed that.  However if I want to create a cube with a texture as well, how to select one shader for the color object and the other when texture is desired?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code the specific error means you never called `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, someBuffer)` before calling `gl.vertexBufferPointer`.

`gl.vertexBufferPointer` copies the reference to the last buffer you bound to `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER` to the attribute's buffer reference.

See this answer:
[What is the logic of binding buffers in webgl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148273/what-is-the-logic-of-binding-buffers-in-webgl/27164577#27164577)