# When to release a Vertex Array Object?

Tags: webgl

What are the guidelines for releasing a Vertex Array Object, e.g. binding to null?

Anecdotally it seems that I can have *similar* shaders and I only need to release after some grouping... or is the best-practice to do it after every grouped shader?

I guess there's another possibility of doing it after every draw call even if they are batched by shader but I don't think that's necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking. "When to release a texture". When you're done using it? I think you mean "unbind" not "release". "release" in most programming means to delete from memory or to at least allow to be deleted from memory.

Assuming you mean when to unbind a Vertex Array Object (VAO) the truth is you never have to unbind a VAO.

As explained else where VAOs contain all attribute state AND the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding so

```
currentVAO = {
  elementArrayBuffer: someIndexBuffer,
  attributes: [
    { enabled: true, size: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: someBuffer, },
    { enabled: true, size: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: someBuffer, },
    { enabled: true, size: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: someBuffer, },
    { enabled: false, size: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: null, },
    { enabled: false, size: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: null, },
    { enabled: false, size: 3, type: gl.FLOAT, stride: 0, offset: 0, buffer: null, },
    ...
    ... up to MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS ...
  ]
};
```

As long as you remember that `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, someBuffer)` effects state inside the current VAO, not global state like `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER)`.

I think that's the most confusing part. Most WebGL methods make it clearer what's being affected `gl.bufferXXX` affects buffers, `gl.texXXX` effects textures. `gl.renderbufferXXX` renderbuffers, `gl.framebufferXX` framebuffers, `gl.vertexXXX` effects vertex attributes (the VAO). etc.. But `gl.bindBuffer` is different at least in this case, it affects global state when binding to `ARRAY_BUFFER` but it affects VAO state when binding to `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

my suggestion would be during initialization follow these steps in this order

```
for each object
  1. create VAO
  2. create vertex buffers and fill with data
  3. setup all attributes
  4. create index buffers (ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER) and fill with data
```

At render time

```
for each object
  1. use program (if program is different)
  2. bind VAO for object (if different)
  3. set uniforms and bind textures
  4. draw
```

What's important to remember is that if you ever call `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` your affecting the current VAO.

Why might I want to bind a `null` VAO? Mostly because I often forget the paragraph above because before VAOs `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` was global state. So, when I forget that and I randomly bind some `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` so that I can put some indices in it I've just changed the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding in the current VAO. Probably not something I wanted to do.  By binding `null`, say after initializing all my objects and after my render loop, then I'm less likely cause that bug.

Also note that if I do want to update the indices of some geometry, meaning I want to call `gl.bufferData` or `gl.bufferSubData` I can sure I'm affecting the correct buffer in one of 2 ways. One by binding that buffer to `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and then calling `gl.bufferData`. The other by binding the appropriate VAO.

If that didn't make sense then assume I had 3 VAOs

```
 // pseudo code
forEach([sphere, cube, torus])
  create vao
  create buffers and fill with data
  create indices (ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)
  fill out attributes
```

Now that I have 3 shapes lets say I wanted to change the indices in the sphere. I could do this 2 ways

One, I could bind the sphere's ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER directly

```
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereElementArrayBuffer)
 gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER...);  // update the indices
```

This has the issue that if some other VAO is bound I just changed it's ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding

Two, I could just bind the sphere's VAO since it's already got the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER bound

```
 gl.bindVertexArray(sphereVAO);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...);  // update the indices
```

This seems safer IMO.

To reiterate, ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding is part of VAO state.

Comment: The comment section here doesn't allow for nice formatting of code...  here's a pastebin link for the same text below: 

https://pastebin.com/wAB06yrg

Thanks! That was great! Just a followup question...

---ON SETUP---
For each object:
1. create/bind vao
2. bind/upload ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
3. bind/upload all attributes
4. bind vao to null

---EACH TICK---
For each object
1. bind vao
2. draw
3. bind vao to null //<-- if I do everything else but this step, I get some visual bugs

However if I only add step 3 in the per-tick it's okay... any idea why that is?

Comment: I have no idea. You should not need tick step 3. I'd have to see more code. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/nkrjad0h/)

Comment: The project is at https://github.com/dakom/pure3d but it'd be a bit tough to point you to exactly where the logic here is... thanks for your help, I'll play around later and see if maybe I missed something. Can you please explain why you unbind after you're finished rendering all objects?

Comment: There is no reason to unbind after rendering all objects really. It's only so that if my bad pattern of making buffers before making VAOs doesn't mess up the currently bound VAO (if I was going to create more geometry later).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you could also move the unbinding to be right before setting buffer data (w/ elements) and it would work as well?

Comment: If you make no mistakes you never have to unbind VAOs but you can unbind wherever you want. My unbinding is to cover my mistakes. Not sure this is a useful comment or not but think that thing that's special about VAOs is the nested state. For almost all other objects you call some function that makes it clear what's going on `gl.texXXX` affects a texture. `gl.bufferXXX` affects a buffer`. `gl.vertexXXX` affects VAOs.  It's not clear at all that `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` also affects a VAO and other targets to `gl.bindBuffer` do not.

Comment: I've posted the contents of a VAO in several other answers. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164577/128511

Comment: Right on! Yeah I was one of the upvotes on your other answer ;) Can you please elaborate on why you call setting buffers first a mistake? I'm doing it too and it feels more organic to set generic data before uploading it for a specific purpose...

Comment: That was just a figure of speech. You can do things in any order you want. My point was the only reason I was binding a null VAO was to avoid messing up the previous VAO's ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding. That only happens because of my init step 3 (bind VAO). If I move that to step 1 there no need for the unbind.  4 steps (make/bind vao, make/fill buffers, make/fill index buffer, set attributes) seems better than 5 steps (make/fill buffers, make/fill index buffer, make/bind vao, set attributes, unbind vao)